# closing a modal when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, overlay

I'm using on my website a kind of modal overlay to display a full size image when clicking on a thumbnail.

here is my JS :

```
$(".mix.photos").on("click", function(){
  var img = $(this).children("img").data("imagefull");
  $("#modal_inner").html("<img src='"+img+"' />");
  $("#modal_inner").fadeIn();


})
```

.mix.photos is my div containing the img.
when clicking on .mix.photos it oppens my #modal_inner wich displats the var img. (the src of the full size image is in my .data("imagefull").
it works great, but I'm trying to add a link to close the #modal_inner when clicking on it.

here is my CSS :

```
#modal_inner{
width: 847px;
height: 374px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
padding-left: 120px;
background-color:rgba(187, 187, 187, 0.8);
display: none;
padding-top: 10px;
z-index: 1000;}
```

and my HTML :

```
<div id="modal_inner">
<div id="modal_close">CLOSE</div>
</div>
```

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following code:

```
   //if you want the modal to close when clicking on the modal itself:
    $("#modal_inner").on("click", function(){
           $(this).fadeOut();
    });
    //if you want the modal to close when clicking on the close button ie <div id="modal_close">CLOSE</div>:
    $("#modal_close").on("click", function(){
           $("#modal_inner").fadeOut();
    });
```

you can add a link to your html markup

```
<div id="modal_inner">
  <div id="modal_close">CLOSE</div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">My Link to Close the modal</a>
</div>
```

and then do the following:

```
$("#modal_inner a").on("click", function(){
   $("#modal_inner").fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

To add close button

```
$(".mix.photos").on("click", function(){
  var img = $(this).children("img").data("imagefull");
  $("#modal_inner").html("<img src='"+img+"' />");
  $("#modal_inner").fadeIn();
  $('<div id="modal_close">CLOSE</div>').appendTo('#modal_inner');

});
```

**Closing function**

```
$(document).on('click','#modal_close',function(){
    $('#modal_inner').empty().fadeOut();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
$(".mix.photos").on("click", function () {
    var img = $(this).children("img").data("imagefull");
    $modal = $("#modal_inner").find('.image').html("<img src='" + img + "' />").end()
    .fadeIn(function() {
        var self = this;
        $(this).on('click', '#modal_close', function() {
            $modal.off().hide();
        });
    });
});
```

You can also delegate close event to the `document` object, but I don't want all the clicks to be checked even when overlay is hidden.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PG2Z8/